# React with ChartJS - how to display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

It's obvious I'm not doing this correctly... in my mind it should work but I don't know.

Here is my chart component:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Chart from 'chart.js';

const canvas = () => (
  <canvas id="LOVE" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
);

export const LOVE = () => {
  const chart = new Chart($('#LOVE'), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: [
        'red',
        'blue',
        'yellow',
      ],
      datasets: [{
        data: [300, 50, 100],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#ff6384',
          '#36a2eb',
          '#ffce56',
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
          '#ff6384',
          '#36a2eb',
          '#ffce56',
        ],
      }],
    },
  });
  return chart;
};
```

Why isn't chart LOVE being displayed?

Also, can I target canvas without jquery $?

Comment: I think you have to put the canvas staff in your html file, then where you use ReactDOM.render ? You don't need jquery with Chart.js, just use document.getElementById, if you prefer to avoid jquery.

Comment: @cocacrave did you ever figure this out?